# Can I set width of jQuery's split button

Tags: css, jquery-ui

At this URL ( http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#splitbutton ) you can see what I mean for splitbutton.

I would set the width of first button (the one which contain text). There is a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In you CSS, you should include this:

```
.ui-button-text {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Or to whatever the desired width is.